# Making a div's height 100% of parent td height (css only)?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, height

http://jsfiddle.net/zVscL/

This sounds really stupid but is there a way to do this? I've been using `height:100%` and I'm getting 0px heights.

I've read about requirements of passing an explicit `height` value from a parent for this to work. Problem is I can't just throw in 28px or any magic number since the parent's height is determined by the content (i.e. it will vary). What are my options?

EDIT: Keep in mind that this is a simplified example of my problem. Yes, I need to use the table. Can't convince the higher ups. (It's only for displaying data, not for page layout fortunately!)

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can not do it using a table.

Comment: The table is there to stay unfortunately, I don't make the decisions :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try with `overflow: auto`. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zVscL/4/).

Comment: Thanks, is using `overflow` the magic bullet for making children 100% height of parents?

Comment: This doesn't work in Opera.  All you see is a blue sliver at the top from the borders.

Comment: Well, no, not really. As cimmanon rightly pointed out, it's not a sure proof way to go, but it can solve this problem in many cases. Anyway, the point here is that the `height: 100%` only works if the parent element has a defined height, and you can't do that. The only other option I can think of is setting your div to `position: absolute; height: 100%;` and the td as `position: relative` (or `absolute`). If that doesn't mess up with other things in your layout, it should do the trick.

Comment: Any reason why CSS can't even do a simple thing like this without resorting to hacks? Forked from your fiddle now I can't get text to vertically align! http://jsfiddle.net/u3X3S/

Comment: Apparently the `overflow` setting messed that up. Maybe you should try a different way: do you really need a floating div there? What about another td instead?

Comment: overflow: auto; along with height:100% works in Chrome only. When I tried the same code in FF and IE it does not work. The properties seem to have no effect at all. I have a div inside a <td> and I want the div to be the same height as the <td>. I can't find a solution anywhere. Tried numerous things.